# Zero padding/stuffing in matlab

Tags: matlab

Basicly I have array like this:

```
[1 2 3 4 5 6]
```

I want to have array like this:

```
[1 0 2 0 3 0 4 0 5 0 6]
```

So it is `L-1` zeros in array where `L` is the number of all values inside array before zero stuffing.

Anyone have idea how to solve it in Matlab?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try this:

```
a = [1 2 3 4 5 6]; 

b = zeros(1, 2 * length(a) - 1);
b(1:2:end) = a;
```

This results in

```
b =

     1     0     2     0     3     0     4     0     5     0     6
```

A shorter version was suggested by **Dan** in the comments:

```
b(1:2:2 * length(a) - 1) = a;
```

Comment: or just `b(1:2:2 * length(a) - 1) = a` and let Matlab fill in the zeros for you

Comment: @Dan: Nice suggestion. Will add it to the answer, if that is ok for you?

Comment: Note that this can give unwanted results if `b` already exists.

Answer (score 2):

If you have signal processing toolbox you can use the [upsample](http://www.mathworks.se/help/signal/ref/upsample.html) function:

```
>> x = 1:5;
>> upsample(x, 2)
ans =
    1     0     2     0     3     0     4     0     5     0
```

Comment: Assuming you have `y = upsample(x, 2)` you can discard the last `0` with `y(end)=[]`

Answer (score 1):

Through `reshape`ing:

```
a = [1 2 3 4 5 6]; 
b = a; % make copy
b(2,:) = 0; % add zeros
b = b(:)'; %'
b(end) = []; % discard last zero
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the most elegant/efficient solution, but the following should work:

```
x = 1:6;
y = zeros(1,2*length(x)-1);
for k=1:length(x)
    y(2*k-1)=x(k);
end
```

Arnaud

Comment: Just seen H.Muster's answer, it is better (doesn't require a for loop).

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing this is:

```
         a=1:6;
         b=zeros(1,2*length(a)-1);
         j=1;
         for i=1:2:length(b)
             b(i)=a(j);
             j=j+1;
         end
```

Comment: just because you've a built in function for something doesn't mean that you couldn't create logic for it.besides this will perform the same thing as the function,it's upto you whether to use it or not.the thing still holds it's significance.

Comment: But it won't perform at all because it won't run in Matlab - at all. If you're just describing an algorithm then rather describe it in psuedocode but why post code from a completely unrelated language when the question is tagged Matlab. This has nothing to do with built in functions (which there aren't any for this).

Comment: HAVE YOU??? This is what you get btw:

 `for(int i=1;i<length(b);i+2)
                  |
Error: Unexpected MATLAB expression.`
 
This isn't even an argument, you posted C code, how do you expect it to run in Matlab?